# NextJS 13 App router different layouts depending on fetch response

Tags: next.js, next.js13

We're currently looking for a way to dynamically render different layouts in a Next.js application based on the data response type.

Let's say we have a URL structure like [slug], which can correspond to either /terms or /otherpage. Within the page, we make a fetch request, and based on the layout property in the response, we need to render either  or  components.Our main concern is achieving this behavior while still benefiting from the features of the Next.js App router.

Has anyone encountered a similar scenario or have any insights on how to approach this problem?

Thank you in advance for your assistance!